# Increase HUD scaling

Tags: borderlands-2

I am running borderlands 2 on a split screen PC (using the split-play mod). But all the writing is too small for me to read anything. I have changed the FOV to 70 so its a bit easier to see into the distance.

I was just wondering if there was a way to make the HUD any bigger in the .ini files?

Comment: You don't need the ini file for that. There is an option in the settings where you can adjust the settings of the HUD.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I have already made it to the maximum size and it is still far too small. I would like to make the maximum bigger like i did with the FOV.

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: 1280 x 720 (the only one that works with the aspect ratio of the TV)